# If I give the same alphabets with different case in password, form is accepting

Tags: java, html, mysql, database

When I try to login the form with correct username and wrong password (with different case in password but same alphabets) it is logging in.

When I try to login the form with correct password and wrong username (with different case in username but same alphabets) it is logging in.

I need to stop login that means how can I make it case sensitive in password. Is it should be done in database while creating the table or we can do it in the program.

## Login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>User Login</title>
<style>
table {  
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;
align: center;
border: 0px;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
margin-top: 55px;
cell-spacing: 10em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
var id = document.signup.LoginId;
var password = document.signup.LoginPassword;

if(id.value == "") {
    window.alert("Error: Username should be filled out.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}
re = /^\w+$/;
if(!re.test(id.value)) {
    window.alert ("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}

if(id.length < 6) {
    window.alert("Error: Username must contain at least 6 charecters.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}
if(id.length > 12) {
    window.alert("Error: Username must not be greater than 12 charecters.");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}

if(password.value != cpassword.value) {
    window.alert("Error: Password and confirm password should be same.");
    password.focus();
    return false;
}

if(password.value != "") {
    if(password.length < 6) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least 6 charecters.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.length > 12) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must not be greater than 12 charecters.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.value == id.value) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must be different from UserName.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[0-9]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one number.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[a-z]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z).");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[A-Z]/;
    if(!re.test(password.value)) {
        window.alert("Error: Password must contain at least one uppercase letters (A-Z).");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}else {
    window.alert("Error: Please check that you've entered your Password.");
    password.focus();
    return false;
}

if (id.value || password.value ! valid) {
    window.alert("The username and/or password are invalid. Please try again");
    id.focus();
    return false;
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search" name="signup" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<table cellpadding="5" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p> If you are new User, please <a href="SignUp.html">SignUp</a>. If you already have an account then SignIn.</p>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr><td>Username</td>
<td><input type=text name=LoginId /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td>
<td><input type=password name=LoginPassword /> </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type=submit value=SignIn /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">If you forgot your password, <a href="ResetPassword"> Reset </a>your password.</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: if my username is sapankumar45 and password is KumRekha23

If I enter these details as sapankumar45 and kumRekh23 (it is working)
or if I enter these details as SAPANkumar45 and KumRekha23 (then also it is working.)

Comment: We need some code. How are you checking the username and password?

Comment: Please provide your form input validation, method of data access, etc.

Comment: Your form (and html) does not check if the password is valid. It just checks if it complies with your requirements. Where is your code where you check the username and password against the known users in your database?

Comment: i don't know how to valid the username and password against database. So, i created error pages for error in servlet. If u can assist me to valid the username and password against database in javascript, it will  be helpful.

Comment: This can't be done with only javascript and mysql. You'll have to learn PHP too. You'll use PHP for server-side authentication of the user and password. You can start [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html).

Comment: I have same problem :( its accepting we need some logic which can check case sensitiveness.